# How to solve C# - SQlite provider problem

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, linq

I have tried all the solutions but I get this error;

**System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.'**

I have installed all packages and dll's.[picture of references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jm0WK.png)

and my App.config;

````
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

    <entityFramework>
     <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>

    <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite" />
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

<connectionStrings><add name="mainEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite.EF6;provider connection string=&quot;data source=C:\Users\MONS\Desktop\XmltoCsvBeta\XmltoCsvBeta\bin\Debug\Data\DB.db&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings></configuration> ```
````

Comment: Perhaps a conflict with x32 and x64 version. Visual Studio 2017 or previous is x32 (don't know for 2019). What is your target: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, Core...? Do you have exception in VS while designing or while running? Do you build AnyCPU, x32 or x64? Have you installed SQLite provider in GAC as x32 or x64 or both, or did you used add by browsing? What provider do you use, which company? I see you have Microsoft.Data.SQLite AND System.Data.SQLite... is it normal? Have you edited the app.config manually or is the designer created it?

Comment: VS 2017 and WinForms. I have tried both x32 and x64 GAC. 

I manually edited the app.config file when searching for a solution. I added provider this one; invariantName="System.Data.SQLite"

and I don't know if it would be a problem to add both them Microsoft.Data.SQLite ass well as System.Data.SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

In case the error pops up at runtime why making selections it may mean that `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` package is missing in project's references. `System.Data.SQLite` includes support for LINQ so it is enough to install this one (instead of just `System.Data.SQLite.Core`).

This helped in my case at least.